# iterating in dataframe using python

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I need to iterate from the Dataframe, where str like

```
http://work4you.su/register
http://vk.com/anime_yes
http://vk.com/anime_yes?z=photo-33172903_414023351%2Fwall-33172903_34658
http://yandex.ru/search?
http://vk.com/anime_yes?z=photo-33172903_413008739%2Fwall-33172903_34522
```

And if `yandex.ru/search` in `url` print `next url == 'yandex'`. I try `url.next() == 'yandex'` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the krux of the problem is finding the next row in a Dataframe

```
for index,row in enumerate(df[column_with_urls][:-1]):
    if 'yandex.ru/search' in row: print df[column_with_urls][index+1] == 'yandex.ru'
```

enumerate allows you to iterate over the rows and indexes, and you can use the index to find the value at the row one below the current one.

Comment: it not print this value, it return `False` to this value

Comment: and it returns `False` not to `index + 1`, it returns it to str, that contain `yandex.ru`